# Lazy loading a font

Tags: css, lazy-loading

I in the middle of a page want to load a font lazily. I use Lazysizes and its plugin, Unveilhooks. This is what the author of the library answered some while ago on this topic: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/issues/169

As for the font, it is Google's Lobster: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lobster

**fonts.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    src: '\wp-content\themes\nonverbis\assets\fonts\lobster\Lobster-Regular.ttf';
}
```

**html**

```
<span class="lazyload" data-link="\wp-content\themes\nonverbis\assets\css\custom\fonts.css"></span>

<p style='font-family: "Lobster script=latin rev=2";'>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

To the best of my ability fonts.css is loaded lazily. And inside the loaded fonts.css the path to the font is correct.

But visually the font of the text has not changed on the page. What can I try next?

Comment: I'm not sure but it's logical that you have some text displayed with a different font, the page needs to be rerendered. In my opinion try to load the font normally.

Comment: But the author of Lazysizes writes that it is possible. But to tell the truth I can't absolutely catch his idea. If fonts can be loaded lazily, then this can speed the site up significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LazyHTML, but you need to add lazyhtml script into Head

```
<script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lazyhtml@1.2.3/dist/lazyhtml.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" debug></script>
```

Add the above script to Head

```
<div class="lazyhtml" onvisible data-lazyhtml>
  <script type="text/lazyhtml">
  <!--
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/nonverbis/assets/css/custom/fonts.css">
   -->
 </script>
</div>
   
<p style='font-family: "Lobster script=latin rev=2";'>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

[Lazy HTML Github](https://github.com/Niresh12495/LazyHTML)